# Building a large app, need some clarification on data managment with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app will loosely be based on houses, so that's how my examples will be formatted below. There will be the ability to create projects that contain info on a house, including each side, and the windows on each side.

Right now I am using vanilla objects to manage my data. I'm using ng-repeat to list out the sides, and their measurements. This is working fine, except I feel like I could be doing it "the angular way" and that I'm not taking advantage of it.

So something like this for instance:

```
function Side(name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.measurements = [];
    this.subtractions = [];
    this.photos = [];
    this.expanded = false;
    this.addMeasurement = function()
    {
        var m = new SideMeasurement();
        m.name = 'Measurement '+(this.measurements.length+1);
        this.measurements.push(m);
    }
}

function SideMeasurement()
{
    this.name = '';
    this.width = '';
    this.height = '';
}


rbpApp.controller('newProjectCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    var defaultSideNames = ['Front','Left Side','Right Side','Back'];
    var sides = [];


    for(var i = 0; i<defaultSideNames.length; i++)
    {
        var side = new Side(defaultSideNames[i]);
        side.addMeasurement();
        sides.push(side);
    }

    $scope.sides = sides;

}]);
```

This is all fine and dandy until I need to add some behaviors to each side. Like potentially change it's appearance, or add behaviors to it based on user interactions. Should each side be a directive? Each side could have multiple measurements, so should they be a directive too? Also, each house is a project, so how can I wrap that into an object that is easily passed between controllers? This data will also have to be stored in local storage, and through a web service.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: one suggestion is move your data object generation to an angular service and inject service in controller. Then as you start moving away from vanilla static data to data pulled from server will only have to change service code, and not controller code. Plus have a lot more flexibility as you modularize routes, directives and other controllers

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If I have a service for say my sides, how could I have multiple sides? I'm assuming that I would have a "sideManager" service that applies CRUD to the side class?

Comment: hard to assist without a higher level concept of goals of app. If you have a starter demo might help. Howver once you start with services you might start seeing how easy it is to share data across app

Comment: if you haven't done so.... go through every step of the tutorial on angular docs site. Great tool for getting into "thinking angular"